# I get an error when I upgrade from xcode 4.3.2 to 4.5.2

Tags: xcode

I have Mac OS X v10.7.5 Lion. I am trying to install Ruby 1.9.3. On the process of doing, I just downloaded xcode 4.5.2 to replace 4.3.2. But when I do it so, I get the following error. How can I fix the problem?

Thanks in advance.

```
The operation can’t be completed because some items had to be skipped. For each item, 
choose File > Get Info, make sure “Locked” is deselected, and then check the Sharing & 
Permissions section. When you are sure the items are unlocked and not designated as 
Read Only or No Access, try again.
```

Comment: You can fix the problem by following the instructions in the error message.

Comment: It does not say which files I need to check though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that I first need to delete the old one and put new one in the Applications.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem until I saw your answer. Seems like an odd way to upgrade an installed app; I wonder if this is normal in the Mac world.